# :hover work on textarea in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-class

I thought that the `:hover` pseudo-class only works on links in IE.  [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/eDP2c/1/) proves this thought wrong when tested in IE8. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE6, it only worked on `a` elements. That was fixed in newer versions.